# Ubuntu can't find my bash-script at /usr/bin/

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

On my first Xubuntu I successfully copied my script `trans.sh` to `/usr/bin`, made executable and after that I can run it in any position of terminal, but my second Xubuntu can't find my script in `/usr/bin/` - and I don't understand why...

```
/usr/bin$ ll | grep trans.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         131 Jun 27 12:30 trans.sh*

/usr/bin$ trans
No command 'trans' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ctrans' from package 'ncl-ncarg' (universe)
 Command 'trang' from package 'trang' (universe)
trans: command not found

/usr/bin$ sh trans.sh
ok

$ $PATH
bash: /home/vitaly/soft/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Extensions have no significance in *nix: if the file is called `trans.sh` then you need to type `trans.sh` to run it - not `trans` - regardless of the fact that it may be a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Start your script with `trans.sh`, that's the full name.

---

*Explanation*

- ```
  rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         131 Jun 27 12:30 trans.sh*
  ```

  - ```
    rwx
    ```

    The owner `root` has **r**ead rights
  - ```
    rwx
    ```

    The owner `root` has **w**rite rights
  - ```
    rwx
    ```

    The owner `root` has e**x**ecutable rights
- ```
  rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         131 Jun 27 12:30 trans.sh*
  ```

  - ```
    r-x
    ```

    The group `root` has **r**ead rights
  - ```
    r-x
    ```

    The group `root` doesn't have write rights (**-**)
  - ```
    r-x
    ```

    The group `root` has e**x**ecutable rights
- ```
  rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         131 Jun 27 12:30 trans.sh*
  ```

  - ```
    r-x
    ```

    All others have **r**ead rights
  - ```
    r-x
    ```

    All others doesn't have write rights (**-**)
  - ```
    r-x
    ```

    All others have e**x**ecutable rights

---

*And more*

1. The name of your script is `trans.sh` and not `trans`

   > ```
   > /usr/bin$ ll | grep trans.sh 
   > -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         131 Jun 27 12:30 trans.sh*
   >
   > /usr/bin$ trans
   > No command 'trans' found, did you mean:
   >  Command 'ctrans' from package 'ncl-ncarg' (universe)
   >  Command 'trang' from package 'trang' (universe)
   > trans: command not found
   > ```
2. If you start `$PATH`, than the content of `$PATH` will be executed, therefore `No such file or directory`.

   > ```
   > $ $PATH
   > bash: /home/vitaly/soft/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
   > No such file or directory
   > ```

   To show the content of `$PATH` use this command

   ```
   echo "$PATH"
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You could try a simpler one like this:

```
 11| grep trans.sh -xrwxr-xr-x 1 %root% %root%
```

and it might work fine this way.